# R-task on Boston dataset part of MASS library in R. Task: Plot accuracy of KNN, K=1:50.

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science

I have done the following but it gives me an error saying NAs introduced by coercion

```
ourBoston=data.frame(Boston)
ourBoston$high.medv=NA
levels(ourBoston$high.medv)=c("no","yes")
ourBoston$high.medv[Boston$medv>25]<-"yes"
ourBoston$high.medv[Boston$medv<=25]<-"no"

result<-rep(0,50)
for (i in 1:50) {
   result=knn(train=data.frame(ourBoston$lstat),test=data.frame(ourBoston$lstat),cl=ourBoston$high.medv,k=i)
  result[i]=sum(as.integer(ourBoston$high.medv))/length(result)
}
qplot(1:50,result[1:50])
```

I have created a column and added it to a new data frame->ourBoston

The lstat variable is the best predictor I have to select for response variable high.medv.

The training and test data set have to be the same.

On running the code I got 50 warnings as: In as.integer(ourBoston$high.medv) : NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that were unclear with your attempts that I've made some assumptions with.

Firstly to clear up some things about your code.
You shouldnt need to wrap something in `data.frame()` if it is already one, check this by looking at the class e.g. `class(Boston)`.

When assigning objects it helps to stick to `<-` or `=`, using `<-` makes it easier to read.

The way you tried to create your factor was a bit of a chore, you can use `ifelse` to assign an outcome based on a boolean check. read more in by typing `?ifelse`.

Within your `for` loop you were assigning the result of the `knn` model to `result` again, this overrode the vector you made to store the results. This is one of the biggest problems with your attempt.

It was also unclear what you were trying to calculate after, I've provided an example of a simple way to determine accuracy. This works by checking if the predicted values are equivilant to the original values in `Boston` and the calculating the `mean`.

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
library(class)

# The call to `data.frame` here is not required, its already one.
# ourBoston=data.frame(Boston)
ourBoston <- Boston

# You are going about the assignment of high.medv poorly
# You can create a factor like so:
ourBoston$high.medv <- factor(ifelse(ourBoston$medv > 25, "yes", "no"))


result <- rep(0, 50)

# seq_along() is preferable, as it makes sure you iterate over each regardless
for (i in seq_along(result)) {

  # you cant assign this to result, you overwrite your vector from before...
  knn_result <- knn(train = ourBoston['lstat'],
                    test = ourBoston['lstat'],
                    cl = ourBoston$high.medv,
                    k = i)

  # not sure what you are trying to do here
  # result[i] <- sum(as.integer(ourBoston$high.medv))/length(result)

  # calculating accuracy
  result[i] <- mean(knn_result == ourBoston$high.medv)

}
qplot(seq_along(result), result)
```